# Why does the grouping function in the for loop not work?

Tags: r

For some reason, the i term in the for loop cannot be used as the grouping name. I have 40 elements in the for loop. I am showing just 2 here as an example.

```
data = data.table(id = c(1,1,1,1,1), a = c(1,1,2,3,NA), b = c(1,2,2,NA,3))

> data
   id  a  b
1:  1  1  1
2:  1  1  2
3:  1  2  2
4:  1  3 NA
5:  1 NA  3

categories = data.table(CATEGORY = c(1,2,3,NA))

> categories
   CATEGORY
1:        1
2:        2
3:        3
4:       NA
```

What I have done:

```
for (i in colnames(data)[2:3]){
  
  dt = data[, .N, i][order(i)]
  setnames(dt, "N", i)
  
  categories = cbind(categories, dt[,2])
}

> categories
   CATEGORY a b
1:        1 2 1
2:        2 2 1
3:        3 2 1
4:       NA 2 1
```

I have also tried the dplyr piping instead of the data.table .N and it did not work:

```
data %>% count(i)
```

What I need:

```
> categories
   CATEGORY a b
1:        1 2 1
2:        2 1 2
3:        3 1 1
4:       NA 1 1
```

Comment: The *reason* your loop doesn't work is that R uses *lazy evaluation*.  expressions are only evaluated when needed.  You don't reference `categories` until the loop has executed.  At this point, `i`, the loop counter is `3`. That said, @RonakShah's comment about reshaping the data is valid: [tidy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html)ness is important conceptually, but will also have the practical benefit of making your life easier and your code more robust.

Answer (score 0):

You could reshape the data instead which would make this easier to calculate.

In `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)

long_data <- melt(data, 'id')
dcast(long_data[, .N, .(variable, value)], value~variable, value.var = 'N')

#   value a b
#1:    NA 1 1
#2:     1 2 1
#3:     2 1 2
#4:     3 1 1
```

Or in `tidyverse` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -id) %>%
  count(name, value) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = n)
```

Comment: Hi Ronak, thanks for the suggestion, in the tidyverse way I have received an error like this: Error: Internal error in `compact_rep()`: Negative `n` in `compact_rep()`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred. maybe I need to mention that there is another variable called "date" that turns this into actually a panel dataset.

Comment: @JantjeHouten Did the `data.table` version work for you? I don't get any such error for `tidyverse` on the dataset that you have shared. Do you probably have `plyr` loaded? Try using `dplyr::count` explicitly in the code.

Comment: I also have no problems running the tidyverse style on this sample dataset. In my actual dataset there is actually another column that is "date" that turns this in a panel dataset. I have removed this date column and followed the code but I received the error.

Comment: @JantjeHouten Can you provide a dataset which is closer to your actual dataset so that we can reproduce the error?

Comment: Thanks for the help Ronak, let me update this in a few hours. Thanks!